# Windows 11+ thread affinities spanning multiple processor groups (explicitly)

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'm trying to figure out how to properly set thread affinities on Windows 11 (or Server 2022, but I'll just say 11 from now on). A short explanation:

Windows 7 through 10 supported more than 64 CPU cores by introducing [Processor Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/processor-groups). In those previous versions one could only set the affinity of a thread to CPUs within a single processor group. It was possible to select groups other than the first one, but it was not possible to span more than one group.

In Windows 11 Microsoft changed things and introduced a new default that the affinity for each thread would span the entire available set of CPU cores. Fantastic. However, once I want to manually change the affinity of a thread, I don't see a possibility of spanning multiple processor groups explicitly (instead of relying on the implicit default that spans all).

A couple of example use cases why that may be relevant:

- Excluding a single core (or a low number of cores) from the affinity of some threads, but keeping all others (because more important things are set to run on those small number of cores).
- If a system has a **lot** of groups (e.g. 256 cores and at least 4 groups), to just span a subset of the processor groups, instead of all of them.

I can use [SetThreadGroupAffinity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processtopologyapi/nf-processtopologyapi-setthreadgroupaffinity) the same as in Windows 7 through 10 to explicitly set the thread affinity to a subset given by a single processor group. To quote the documentation (emphasis added):

> Starting with Windows 11 and Windows Server 2022, on a system with more than 64 processors, process and thread affinities span all processors in the system, across all processor groups, by default. The SetThreadGroupAffinity function **restricts** a thread's affinity to the processors over the single processor group specified by the given GroupAffinity. This group will also become the thread's primary group.

If I use the even older function [SetThreadAffinityMask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadaffinitymask) on Windows 11 it will similarly restrict the affinity of the thread to the selected threads, but just within the primary processor group. To quote the documentation again:

> Starting with Windows 11 and Windows Server 2022, on a system with more than 64 processors, process and thread affinities span all processors in the system, across all processor groups, by default. The dwThreadAffinityMask must specify processors in the thread's current primary group.

But there doesn't appear to be any new function that has been added to Windows 11 that can explicitly set the CPU affinity mask of a thread to span multiple processor groups - the only way to have that is to rely on the default, but I can't find any way of doing that explicitly. (I haven't even found a way to revert to the defaults entirely.)

What is new in Windows 11 are additional functions in the [CPU Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/cpu-sets) subsystem (which was added in Windows 10 initially), but those aren't hard affinities to specific cores - those are just suggestions that the scheduler may ignore. So that doesn't help me when I want to modify the explicit (hard) affinities of a process.

Am I missing something? Or is this something that Microsoft has completely overlooked?

Comment: That's a lot of news to me. [`SetThreadSelectedCpuSetMasks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setthreadselectedcpusetmasks) looks interesting. Have you had a look at that?

Comment: Yeah, that's the CPU sets API I mentioned, and from the documentation it's not equivalent to the hard affinities. I haven't tried it yet though.

Comment: @chris_se That was a very long description for a very simple question. So I'm a little lost of what EXACTLY you are actually asking for. What is your goal that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @RemyLebeau To give an example: if I have a system with e.g. 256 CPU cores in 4 processor groups with 64 cores each, I want to be able to specify an affinity mask that says that a specific thread can be scheduled on 128 different cores (belonging to two of the processor groups, e.g. group 2 and 3, but not 0 and 1) -- but from what I read in the API documentation I can either leave the default as-is (schedule potentially on all cores) or only select a single processor group for the affinity mask, restricting me to at most 64 possible cores in the affinity mask.

Comment: @chris_se In that case, I think Ted is right, you need to use `SetThreadSelectedCpuSetMasks()` to specify a thread affinity on multiple processor groups at a time. Give it an array of `GROUP_AFFINITY` elements, where each `GROUP_AFFINITY` specifies a specific processor group, and an affinity mask within that group.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Many thanks for pushing me to take a look at `SetThreadSelectedCpuSetMasks()` again; the Microsoft documentation is not very clear about what's going on with that, and it appeared to me that it's just a suggestion for the scheduler. It does actually work, but with some caveats. I've written up what I've found during testing in my answer to this question, since this information could be useful for other people as well.

Answer (score 3):

I've now played around with `SetThreadSelectedCpuSetMasks()` a bit and found that it does in fact solve my problem, but with some caveats.

Windows starting with version 11 appears to have two completely different affinity APIs: the traditional ones (that can only apply to at most one processor group), or the new ones defined by `SetThreadSelectedCpuSetMasks()`. I've observed the following behavior:

- If both are set Windows takes effectively an `AND` mask of the affinities. So if for example the `SetThreadGroupAffinity()` mask is set to 0x03 (CPUs 0 and 1) for group 0 and the `SetThreadSelectedCpuSetMasks()` mask is set to to 0x06 (CPUs 1 and 2) for group 0, the result is that the thread will only run on CPU 1.

  - However, if there is no overlap between both masks, then **only** the `SetThreadGroupAffinity()` (or equivalently `SetThreadAffinityMask()`) mask is applied, and the mask set by `SetThreadSelectedCpuSetMasks()` is ignored. (It can still be re-read via `GetThreadSelectedCpuSetMasks()` and there is no indication purely from that API that there would be an issue there.)
- In contrast to what's written in the documentation, the `SetThreadSelectedCpuSetMasks()` still appears to be a hard mask (other than the "will be ignored fully" logic when there's no overlap with the "traditional" mask), i.e. not just a suggestion to the scheduler. I've never observed a thread being run on a core that it wasn't supposed to with the new-style affinities set this way.
- Setting either mask will have no effect on the other mask. For example, calling `SetThreadSelectedCpuSetMasks()` will have no effect on `GetThreadGroupAffinity()`, and similarly vice-versa.
- I still haven't found anything in the API to undo the effect of `SetThreadGroupAffinity()`/`SetThreadAffinityMask()` restricting the affinity mask to just a single processor group.

To summarize, I think the following logic is probably the best way of doing things:

- On Windows before 7 use `SetThreadAffinityMask()` (it doesn't support more than 64 CPUs anyway) (Probably not relevant anymore nowadays, just wanted to mention it for completeness sake.)
- On Windows 7 through 10 use `SetThreadGroupAffinity()` to select a single processor group and assign the affinity there. (The OS simply can't schedule threads across processor groups.)
- On Windows 11 onwards **never** use the `SetThreadAffinityMask()`/`SetThreadGroupAffinity()` APIs to set the thread affinity, because we *have* to rely on the default behavior (without such a call) that all threads can be scheduled across all processor groups. Instead **only** use the `SetThreadSelectedCpuSetMasks()` API to set affinities. And pray that no third-party library accidentally calls `SetThreadAffinityMask()`/`SetThreadGroupAffinity()` (or even worse `SetProcessAffinityMask()` for that matter), because that'll undo the default behavior of Windows 11 to schedule across all groups, and there appears to be no way back.

Side note: for programs that still need to run on Windows 10, I intend to use `LoadLibraryA("kernel32.dll");` and `GetProcAddress(library, "SetThreadSelectedCpuSetMasks");` to a) determine if those calls are supported (`GetProcAddress` will return `nullptr` on Windows 10, but not on 11, so it's a good way of detecting this feature) and b) to invoke them from a program compiled with a lower `_WIN32_WINNT` than required for Windows 11.

I hope this helps other people who might run into the same issue.

I'll leave this question open in case anyone still has an idea of an API function that can be called to get rid of the "restrict to a single processor group" behavior of `SetThreadGroupAffinity()`/`SetThreadAffinityMask()` and return to the default behavior regarding that mask. (In that case I would use that call before calling `SetThreadSelectedCpuSetMasks()` to ensure that only the latter call is relevant to the thread affinities, regardless of what was previously called in the process.)

Comment: "On Windows 11 onwards never use the SetThreadAffinityMask()/SetThreadGroupAffinity() APIs to set the thread affinity, because we have to rely on the default behavior (without such a call) that all threads can be scheduled across all processor groups." This might be what you want, but many applications will want to restrict specific threads to specific groups. For instance to make sure that a thread only runs on a particular NUMA node.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sure, I'm not saying "don't use common sense", I just wanted to understand the *how* this works. Obviously you have to think about the specific use case you're using before actually assigning affinities yourself.

Comment: _"In contrast to what's written in the documentation..."_ - What part of the documentation are your referring to? I suggested using `SetThreadSelectedCpuSetMasks` because when I read the documentation it looked like the hard setting you needed instead of just a suggestion to the scheduler.

Comment: *"to invoke them from a program compiled with a lower `_WIN32_WINNT` than required for Windows 11"* - Do you know what the `_WIN32_WINNT` constant for Windows 11 actually is? A microsoft.com page lists the values for the earlier versions but not 11.

Comment: @AJM Interesting: in `processthreadsapi.h` the function definition is masked by `#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_FE)`, but `_WIN32_WINNT_WIN10_FE` is not actually declared anywhere in the SDK (I've checked that it's latest Win11 SDK version, 10.0.22621.0) and Google yields 0 results for that constant. Since I'm dynamically accessing the function anyway, I've never stumbled upon the issue, but you apparently can't set `_WIN32_WINNT` to a value that enables these functions directly, because the corresponding constant is not defined at all...

Comment: That *is* interesting. Do you know what the "FE" stands for? I'm wildly guessing at something like "Further Editions" or "Future Editions".

Comment: According to some published Zig source, (inc. http://ratfactor.com/zig/stdlib-browseable/target.zig.html) FE is Win 10 20H2, MN is 20H1 and VB is 19H2. No indication of why those particular 2-letter codes were chosen for each of those versions.

Comment: @AJM Though my up to date Windows 10 22H2 VM doesn't have `SetThreadSelectedCpuSetMasks()` exported from `kernel32.dll` (Windows 11 does in contrast), so either Zig or the definitions in the Windows SDK are wrong when it comes to this. When I find the time I'll update the post to add the information that you need to dynamically load the functions at the moment.